# How TensorFlow Lucid/visualization by optimisation actually works?

Tags: tensorflow, lucid

I try to understand this article

https://distill.pub/2017/feature-visualization/
also I tried to get into code
https://github.com/tensorflow/lucid
and check other articles and videos

And still I don't really understand how we can to optimise input noise image according to some one neuron? Or according to layers...  How we "ignore" other neurons when we try to optimise and see effect of only neuron/layers which are interested for us? How we can say "Ok, generate this image which is optimise neuron/layer activation"? How these generated images(representations) affected by other neurons
(Can we manipulate them? if yes how to choose level of effect of other neurons? and if yes how we can understand something if we can tweak every neuron in previous layers and see new representation everytime)? Which difference between multiplication weights on input and this optimisation?
Can somebody share information about it?

p.s
Sorry for long read and "neuron" word

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is that I found
https://github.com/greentfrapp/lucent
https://github.com/Mayukhdeb/torch-dreams

if I understand correctly in pytorch this is easier to implement because of register_backward_hook function which is gives you simple way to retrieve layers outputs ...